# Debug python, determine which condition was true

Tags: python, python-2.7, debugging

I have a fairly long list of conditions that might be true in order to satisfy a particular if statement. 
I'm trying to debug and find out which condition was met since it shouldn't be, is there any better way than testing each condition individually? something like:

```
if (xpr1 or xpr2 or xpr3 .......):
     print "xpr# was true"
```

OR better.

```
     print "all variables" from true condition
```

Python 2.7

Comment: what about [`any(xpr1, xpr2, ...)`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#any)? to debug you could use `[bool(x) for x in (xp1, xpr2, ...)]`.

Comment: @hiro all() returns True, if all elements are True,  if (...) from UserZer0 schould return True, if at least one element is True.

Comment: @Humbalan yes, just noticed and corrected.

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> a = False
>>> b = True
>>> c = False
>>> print [name for name in ['a', 'b', 'c'] if locals()[name]]
['b']
```

Comment: Alternatively, if typing out quotes and commas gets annoying for many variables, you can instead just write `'a b c'.split()`.

Comment: @AlexHall your comment massively improves the usefulness of this answer! Would not have thought about that!

Comment: Or, since they are single character names: `list('abc')`.

Answer (score 2):

There isn't really any better way than testing each condition individually, but you can do that compactly in a list comprehension, eg:

```
conditions = (xpr0, xpr1, xpr2, xpr3)
print [i for i, xpr in enumerate(conditions) if xpr]
```

will print a list of the indices of expressions that are true. However, this won't perform the short-circuiting that you get with `or`.

Of course, you can force short-circuiting by using a "traditional" `for` loop, with a `break` statement, eg:

```
for i, xpr in enumerate(conditions):
    if xpr:
        print i, xpr
        break
```

although this isn't exactly the same as the short-circuiting performed by

```
if xpr0 or xpr1 or xpr2 or xpr3:
```

because we've already pre-computed all the expressions in the `conditions` list.

---

As hiro protagonist mentions in the comments, you can test if any of those expressions are true with

```
any(conditions)
```

and that *will* short-circuit in the same way as the traditional `for` loop code above.

FWIW, normally, one uses `any` and `all` on a generator expression rather than a list comp, since that avoids unnecessary evaluation of expressions after a short-circuit point is reached, but that's not applicable here.